# Variable not in variable explorer in Spyder

Tags: python, variables, spyder

new to python and new to Spyder but below is my code:

```
#calculating the probability that a data point belongs to a normal distribution
dVal = stats.norm(mu[0], sigma[0])  
dVal.pdf(15)
#passing in array to prob density function to get prob density at every  point in data set
dVal.pdf(X[:,0])[0:50]
```

I got this code from:
http://www.johnwittenauer.net/machine-learning-exercises-in-python-part-8/
The rest of the code I understand, this bit I am slowly trying to understand but my question is why does the dVal variable not appear in my variable explorer in Spyder? Is this simply due to incorrect logic in my code or is it to do with the type of variable or is there another reason?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) dVal is an object.

From what I remember of Spyder, only simple builtin variables show up in the variable explorer.

You can try using the Object Inspector tab in that same window in order to get some insight into objects.

You can also type help(dVal) to see the documentation.

You can also type dir(dVal) to see the list of attributes and methods.